# Proper Specification of Balanced Repeated Replicate Weights in R Survey Package

Tags: r, survey, weights

I am trying to properly apply BRR (balanced repeated replicate) weights in the R Survey Package and I am using the National Center for Education Statistics ELS 2002 dataset.  I am not sure how to figure out what to specify for the combined.weights argument, which should be true if the replicate weights already include the sample weight (which the R manual says is typically the case).  How do I go about finding out if the replicate weights "include" the sample weight or not?
If the combined.weights argument is true, then the scale and rscales arguments need to be specified and I am not sure how to go about that either.  I have seen some examples, but they seem to differ by the dataset involved.  Any advisement would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to CV. It might help your potential respondents if you were to explain the acronyms such as "BRR." Thank you.

Comment: Balanced repeated replication